# Convert from HTML to string XQuery

Tags: html, string, dom, xquery

I have text below

`<p>Some Text. </p><p><br></p><p>Another Text.</p><p><br></p><p>Bla bla bla.</p>`

I need to convert it in:

"Some Text.

Another Text.

Bla bla bla."

How can i do it in XQuery?

Comment: Which processor are you using? It's easiest to parse the HTML into something well-formed and then XPath to snag the `text()` nodes, but depending on processor and XQuery version may need extension functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **MarkLogic**, you can use the [`xdmp:unquote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote) function with the `repair-full` option:

```
let $html := "<p>Some Text. </p><p><br></p><p>Another Text.</p><p><br></p><p>Bla bla bla.</p>"
let $xhtml := xdmp:unquote($html, "", "repair-full")
return $xhtml//text()
```

Which will return a sequence of `text()` nodes. If you want a single string, you could change the return to `fn:string-join($xhtml//text(), "&#10;")`

In **BaseX**, you could use the [`html:parse()`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/HTML_Module#html:parse) method

In **Saxon**, you could use the [`saxon:parse-html()`](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/functions/saxon/parse-html.html) method